# How do I change a section of a host name permanently on multiple host names as a root user?

Tags: etc

I am doing a project for uni and an unsure how to proceed i have been given the task of changing hosts name from one thing to another on a unix box I am logged in to the box as root

the host name is `garnet.bct.bolton.ac.uk garnet` 
I need to change `.bct` to `.amt`

The new host name should be `garnet.amt.bolton.ac.uk garnet`

I have multiple hostname in `cat /etc/hosts` and they all need changing from `bct` to `amt`

I think I need to use `grep` but that is as far as I have gotten

`cat /etc/hosts | grep bct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo've not stated what your *nix is. But...

From what I can gather, you have two tasks there:

1. Change the hostname of the unix box
2. Change how that unix box resolves other systems on the network.

For the first, you need to edit the file `/etc/hostname` and change it.

```
nano /etc/hostname
```

For the second, you need to change all the instances of `bct` to `amt` in `/etc/hosts`.  You can either do this with an interactive editor or you can script it with `sed`.

Interactively:

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

With `sed`:

First, run:

```
sed 's/\.bct\.bolton/\.amt\.bolton/g` /etc/hosts
```

and make sure that it looks ok.  That simply shows you what it would change.  To make the changes, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/\.bct\.bolton/\.amt\.bolton/g` /etc/hosts
```

Comment: thank you i will give it a try. i thought that sed only changed the display output though? also i dont know what *nix is

Comment: `sed` with no option will print the changed file to stdout (terminal normally).  With the `-i` option it changes the file `in-place`.  It's in the `man` page - `man sed` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

`sed -i 's/\.bct/\.amt/g' /etc/hosts`

Also, please be aware that if you are changing the hostname of the machine in which you are logged in, then making change in /etc/hosts alone will not suffice. If you are on Centos/Fedora/RHEL, the hostname has to be changed in the file /etc/sysconfig/network as well.

Comment: would i have to do the same if i am using linux minx? and thank you